# Unable to run java program from CLI while Netbeans runs same program correclty

Tags: java, netbeans

Following program runs fine with Netbeans IDE but when i try to run from command prompt i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Gcd (wrong name: algo
rithms/Gcd)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

package algorithms;

public class Gcd {

public static int ComputeGcd(int number1, int number2){
    if(number2 == 0){ return number1;}
    else{
         int remainder = number1 % number2;
         return ComputeGcd(number2,remainder);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 32;
    int b = 12;
    System.out.println(ComputeGcd(a,b));

} 

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be in the `src` directory, running these commands:

```
...\src> javac algorithms\Gcd.java
...\src> java algorithms.Gcd
```

(You don't *have* to compile from that directory, but I would suggest you do so.)

The `java` command takes the fully-qualified class name, which includes the package name.

Answer (score 1):

move two levels above i.e. src  and then do a java algorithms.Gcd

Answer (score 1):

Have you created directory for `algorithm`, try running the program by commenting `package algorithm`, it will work...Once assured, you can use

```
javac algorithms.Gcd.java; 
java algorithms.Gcd`
```

as mentioned by @JonSkeet, you can learn more about the package structures [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package),

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to see what classpaths Netbeans is providing to Java that your CLI command isn't.

Try removing the `package` call if you're not using packages, as it can lead to complications.

Comment: and make sure you `javac` after doing so

Comment: Using the default package is *not* an appropriate answer here. It's a bad practice, and should be avoided - the correct approach is to know how to use packages properly.

Comment: +1 @JonSkeet, I completely agree with you, but dont you think some times even the best practices are also most complex ones... However I packages must be used where ever possible, but at the same time too much use can increase complexity.... Need your views on it ? I know you are the right person to ask this question ?

Comment: @rahul: I only ever write classes in the default package for throwaway test code. I'm not sure what you mean by "too much use" here. It's not like I'm suggesting *extraneous* complexity here - just structure which is already present in the code and which is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Got it.. I am also a strong supporter of Good Coding practices, in fact McConnell's **Code Complete** is my all time favorite texts.. I really agree with your thoughts and possibly the answer of my question too much specific about the project scenarios. . . Thanks for your reply